# Resetting Solr index fails

Tags: apache, solr, indexing

Currently if I send the following delete-by-query command to Solr, the index should be cleared of all entries:

```
//<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
http://<solr-server>:<port>/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*%3A*%3C%2Fquery%3E%3C%2Fdelete%3E
```

The response I get from the solr server seems normal:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">13</int>
  </lst>
</response>
```

However, if I restart Solr by restarting Tomcat, then perform a select query, I still retrieve indexed search results.  Why are these results not deleted?

(Note: on my laptop I installed a Solr instance, and this process works fine when deleting the index)

Comment: `Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found later on that the delete-by-query commands were failing because file permissions on our linux server were preventing Solr from performing the updates.  Using a `chmod` command fixed this.

Any suggestions for security on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After the delete you need to send a commit query as well:

```
http://<solr-server>:<port>/solr/update?stream.body=<commit/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  After some more troubleshooting, we realized the solution had to do with file-permissions.